# Conditionally show settings page?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I want to check if the user is a moderator before displaying a certain page in my settings. Here's how my storyboard is laid out:

[image: storyboard]

When the user taps the "Invite users to pack" I want to check if a certain variable is true before pushing the view.

The problem is that if I hook up the cell to the UIViewController to its right then it automatically transitions when the cell is pressed. How would I implement some sort of code like?

```
if (isMod == true) {
  // Show page
} else {
  print("ACCESS DENIED")
}
```

Comment: Are you using segue or pushing view controller by coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using segue, check it in `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` in viewClass with tableView. Or you're using code to push (to navigationController), you can check before `.pushViewController(viewController:, animated:)`